# Jquery bind 'copied' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's popover component to display a bit of text to be copied by the user. I need to make the popover disappear after the user has copied the text.

So far I had tried:

```
$('.popover-content input').select().bind('copy', function () {
    $('#Link').popover('hide');
});
```

The problem is that the copy event seems to run the bound function before the clipboard contents is updated. This means that when the copy is actually triggered the popover DOM element has been destroyed along with the text field.

I had thought to set the popover css to `display: none;` but that doesn't really feel like a very tidy or elegant way of performing this action.

Does anyone know if there is a 'copied' event or any other way of doing this that is cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

use `unbind()` method:

```
$('.popover-content input').select().bind('copy', function () {
    $('#Link').popover('hide');
    $(this).unbind('copy');
});
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to resolve the issue. The clipboard doesn't update with the contents of the input field before the popover element is removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for [Underscore#defer](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) allows you to defer an action and allow the function calling it to continue running and finish execution before your defer function kicks in. Best thought of as a non-blocking `setTimeout`.

Here is the finished code:

```
$('.popover-content input').select().bind('copy', function () {
    _.defer(function () {
        $('#Link').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: A non-blocking `setTimeout` as opposed to…?

Comment: Well, maybe using the wrong terminology there so please forgive. My point is that ```setTimeout``` does not allow the parent function to finish execution until it's callback has completed execution. Just so I have things clear what would be the correct term for this type of behaviour?

Comment: That’s the correct terminology for what you’re describing, but… it’s not right! `setTimeout` returns immediately, always. If I had to take a guess, I would say `_.defer(f)` is sugar for `setTimeout(f, 0)`.

Comment: But then why would setTimeout not be working in the situation described but defer works perfectly... Just a little curious is all

Comment: How did you try using `setTimeout` originally? It’s not in your question…

Comment: It's a little difficult to show the code in context as it is part of a pretty large application. I've just done some further testing and in an [isolated situation](http://jsfiddle.net/vqp5g/2/) it does work perfectly. But setTimeout does not work in the situation I have it (inside a backbone sub view) so there must be something else causing the behaviour to change.

Comment: Two unlikely possibilities, but: a) does anything override `setTimeout` (you can check using `console.log('' + setTimeout);`), or b) are you using CoffeeScript?

Comment: No CoffeeScript and setTimeout comes back as being the natively implemented version in Chrome's JS engine. So I'm more than a little flummoxed.